# Regular expression with dynamic text

Tags: java

I am in Java and I need to do a replace and need a little help with a regular expression.

```
String temp = "/Users/john/core-xxx/testSomething.java"
```

I am using xxx as the place holder for the dynamic text. So my goal is to replace the core-xxx with the text called testingPlatform. Thanks for the help

So System.println(someNewVariable); should show

```
"/Users/john/testingPlatform/testSomething.java"
```

Comment: It is not going to be xxx. it could be core-doc or core-sos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do

```
String newTemp = temp.replaceAll("core-\\w+", "testingPlatform");
```

where `\w+` matches one or more word characters (`[a-zA-Z_0-9]`)

Filenames can contain unicode characters so better

```
String newTemp = temp.replaceAll("core-\\p{L}+", "testingPlatform");
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this replaceAll...

```
 replaceAll("yours","Replacement");
```

Comment: in the input string "core-xxx", xxx part is dynamic, so it can be core-abc, core-efg etc.. so OP wants a Regex

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the `replace` and `replaceAll` methods of [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

In your case you should do the following:

```
System.println(temp.replaceAll("core-\\w+", "testingPlatform"));
```

Comment: I just added an example about how to get what the user is looking for.